# Reinitialize webservice defined as a spring bean

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I have a spring bean definition for some external webservices that tend to be unreliable so I can foresee a day where I start up my web application and connectivity to the webservice is unavailable, which would cause the intialization of the spring bean to fail, and consequently cause dependency problems to the other parts of the system that would rely on this bean.

```
    <bean id="services.ext.service" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.ext.WebService"/>
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://www.somehost.com/ws/blah.wsdl"/>
        <property name="serviceName" value="Service"/>
    </bean>
```

My question is if there is a way I can setup this bean to be lazy-initialized AND in the event that the bean fails somehow trigger the bean to be re-initialized until it is successful?  Or perhaps theres a better way of setting up the external webservice.

Comment: Can't you just wrap this in another bean (e.g. some sort of bean state manager) that keeps track of this beans state, and re-initializes it when necessary?

Comment: I guess so, but was hoping there may be something in spring that would take care of things for me somehow.

Comment: Could very well be. Spring is very big. Hopefully someone else will come along and shed some light on the issue.